# making an XML dump of a MediaWiki using dumpBackup.php

Tags: mediawiki

Using the MediaWiki maintenance script called `dumpBackup.php` I want to create an XML dump of my MediaWiki.

To do this you have to login to the server using an SSH client, I'm using Putty (Windows), but I also tried it on OSX using Terminal.

According to the [MediaWiki Manual for dumpBackup.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDumpBackup.php) this is done using these commands:

```
cd w/maintenance
php dumpBackup.php --full >d:\backup.xml
```

Since I am using GoDaddy hosting the last line is a bit different for me. The reason is that SSH for GoDaddy by default still uses php4 (unlike the HTTP server). For this reason my command is (assuming you are also in the maintenance folder):

```
usr/local/php5/bin/php dumpBackup --full >d:\backup.xml
```

The however, all this does for me is print everything on the screen and no file is created. Does anybody know why this is and how to make sure the file **is** created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out the `>` from the original example:

```
php dumpBackup.php --full >d:\backup\dump.xml
```

The `>` tells the shell to redirect the output of the script to the file `d:\backup\dump.xml` instead of the screen.

By the way, `d:\backup\dump.xml` is a Windows file name.  Since your server seems to be using a Unixish OS (probably Linux), you probably don't want to use that filename.  However, if you don't mind having the file created in your current directory, just plain `dump.xml` will work fine on both Windows and *nix.

You could also try e.g. `~/dump.xml` or `$HOME/dump.xml` (both of which create the file in your home directory) or `$TMP/dump.xml` (which creates it in the directory designed for temporary files, usually `/tmp`.)  This could be useful if you don't have enough space available in the directory you installed MediaWiki in.

To see how much space you do have, try the commands `df -h` (which shows the amount of actual free space) and `quota -vs` (which shows how much of that space you're allowed to use, if that has been limited).  For more help with these commands, try [`man df`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df) and/or [`man quota`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/quota).

Comment: Thanks! regarding the `>` comment. I did include this in the commands I used (therefore I edited the question). I'll try your other comments asap.

Comment: That's odd. The symptoms you describe (output sent to the screen) are exactly what one would expect if the `>` sign was not there.  If you _did_ include it, you should not have seen any output to the screen. Could you please try copying and pasting the _exact_ commands you used from your terminal window (or even uploading a screenshot)?

Comment: By the way, you might want to take a look at a Unix shell tutorial, such as [Learning the Shell](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php) or [UNIX Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/unix/). They'll help you understand just what all those commands are doing and why they work the way they do.

Comment: hey, Ok thanks for all the input I'll try to post what you ask for in about two hours

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. I think the thing I did wrong was use the windows file indication like you said. But why would the MediaWiki Manual use this as well, don't most servers run on linux?

Comment: There are quite a few webhosts out there using IIS on Windows. Some even market it as a feature. Personally, I don't see why, but they do exist and MediaWiki (mostly) runs just fine on such systems.

Comment: I guess you're right, but the cross-platform option of just `>backup.xml` whould seem more at hand to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10980/discussion-between-bquast-and-ilmari-karonen)